# $\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^n \left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}{n} \right) e^{-2x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm practicing for the exam of Real Analysis (It is about Lebesgue integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$).
I've encountered the following problem but I'm having some trouble solving it: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^n \left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}{n} \right) e^{-2x} dx$$

My attempt: 
$$
\int_0^n \left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}{n} \right) e^{-2x} dx \leq \int_0^n \left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}{n} \right)dx = n - \frac{n^{27}}{28} \to -\infty \text{ as } n \to \infty 
$$
Therefore: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^n \left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}{n} \right) e^{-2x} dx = -\infty$$

Is this right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The expression in the parenthesis is not positive, so the inequality need more work to justify. It is highly likely fails to hold.

Comment: How do you justify the first inequality? Note that $ue^{-2x}\le u$ only if $u\ge0$, and $\left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}n\right)$ is not positive over the whole of $(0,n)$.

Comment: you're right.. thank you :D

Comment: A rule of thumb: integrate the pointwise limit first and then see whether you can justify it. In this case the pointwise limit is simply $e^{-2x}$, but there is some reason to be worried that maybe the negative values of the integrand on $[n^{1/27},n]$ may be significant enough to create problems. To address this, you use a convergence theorem, most commonly the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Ian yes, that is what I thought. I thought that the negative values might indeed cause some problems. Then, in the attempt to conclude, I made that huge mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. *Don't "lose" the $e^{-2x}$ in your bound, it's the crucial factor to make things work.*

Rewrite $$\int_0^n \left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}{n}\right)e^{-2x} dx
= \int_{[0,\infty) }\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{(-x)^{27}}{n}\right)e^{-2x}\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(x)}_{f_n(x)} dx$$
and note that
$$
\forall x_0\geq 0,\qquad f_n(x_0) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^{-2x_0}\\\tag{pointwise convergence}
$$
while
$$
\forall n\geq 1, \forall x\geq 0, \qquad |f_n(x)| \leq \underbrace{(1+x^{27})e^{-2x}}_{g(x)} \tag{domination}
$$
while $g$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$:
$
\int_{[0,\infty)} g(x)dx < \infty$.

Can you conclude via the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: Your statement about $f_n(x_0)$ is not correct.

Comment: @Ian Wow, indeed. Thank you, I fixed it -- I think I hallucinated a $n$ in the exponent (and even then, it failed at $0$).

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply out the parens and split the integral into two, the first is

$$\int_0^n e^{-2x} \; dx \to \frac{1}{2}.$$

The other integral: Take the $\frac{1}{n}$ outside.  Do integration by parts $27$ times.  You get

$$\frac{1}{n}(\mbox{polynomial})e^{-2n} \to 0.$$

So the limit is $1/2.$

Comment: The second part results in $\frac{p(n)e^{-2n}-p(0)}{n}$, and the second term only goes to zero because of the $1/n$. In particular, you can't just factor out $e^{-2n}$ and leave a polynomial behind, if that were the case then the Gamma function at all positive integer arguments would vanish...